# Fill week based on first and last week in the data frame

Tags: r

I have a Dataframe like below. I want fill in week and year for each name based on the first week. What I am looking for is just minimum week of each name and the fill all the way until the most recent week of the most recent year.

```
structure(list(Name = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("John", 
"Mary"), class = "factor"), Year = c(2021L, 2021L, 2020L, 2021L
), Week = c(1L, 5L, 3L, 5L), Total = c(3L, 2L, 1L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Desired output

```
Name Year Week Total

    John 2021 1 3
    John 2021 2 0
    John 2021 3 0
    John 2021 4 0
    John 2021 5 1
    Mary 2020 3 1
    Mary 2020 4 0
    Mary 2020 5 0
    .
    .
    .
    Mary 2021 4 0
    Mary 2021 5 2

My code:
data %>%
  complete(Week = seq(min(Week), 53), fill = list(Total = 0))
  fill(c(Name, year))
```

Comment: please always share code to your data. You can use `dput(data)`

Comment: is there a way to do complete(Week = seq(min(Week)):53, fill = list(Total = 0))

Answer (score 1):

You may try

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(yw = ifelse(Week < 10, paste0(c(Year,"0",Week,"1"), collapse = ""),
                     paste0(c(Year,Week,"1"), collapse = "")) %>% as.Date(., "%Y%U%u")) %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  complete(yw = seq(min(yw), max(yw), by = 7, fill = list(Name = Name))) %>%
  mutate(Year = lubridate::year(yw), 
         Week = lubridate::week(yw),
         Total = ifelse(is.na(Total), 0, Total)) %>%
  select(-yw)

   Name   Year  Week Total
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 John   2021     1     3
 2 John   2021     2     0
 3 John   2021     3     0
 4 John   2021     4     0
 5 John   2021     5     2
 6 Mary   2020     3     1
 7 Mary   2020     4     0
 8 Mary   2020     5     0
 9 Mary   2020     6     0
10 Mary   2020     7     0
# ... with 50 more rows
```